# Using custom serializer in Ember with hal json from Apigility

Tags: ember.js, laminas-api-tools, hal-json

So I'm in the process of building out the front end of our site, and long story short, the location of our API call is through [apigility](https://apigility.org/). I'm fairly new to Ember, so I've been having to piece of a lot of info together on the best way to make this work. apigility is set up to give a REST service, but the output is in the following format:

```
{
  _links: {
    self: {
      href: "http://localhost:8888/article?page=1"
    },
    first: {
       href: "http://localhost:8888/article"
    },
    last: {
      href: "http://localhost:8888/article?page=1"
    }
  },
  _embedded: {
    article: [
      {
        nid: 1,
        body_value: "Lorem Ipsum etc etc",
        created: 1487176722,
        _links: {
          self: {
            href: "http://localhost:8888/article/1"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  page_count: 1,
  page_size: 25,
  total_items: 1,
  page: 1
}
```

To start with since I'm kind of just trying for a proof of concept, here's my serializer:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
    primaryKey: 'nid',
    normalizeResponse: function(store, primaryModelClass, payload, id, requestType) {   
        return {
            data: payload._embedded.article,                
        };
    }
});
```

I'm also using the RESTAdapter for my apadpter.

And finally my model for article.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    body_value: DS.attr('string'),
    nid: DS.attr('number')
});
```

The error that it's currently giving me is:

```
You must include an 'id' for undefined in an object passed to 'push'
```

From that error I feel like it's correctly getting the 'article' portion from my api call, but the primaryKey portion doesn't seem to be in effect.

If I remove the contents of my serializer, I get the following list of errors:

```
ember.debug.js:7062WARNING: Encountered "embedded" in payload, but no model was found for model name "embedded" (resolved model name using ember-drupal@serializer:application:.modelNameFromPayloadKey("embedded"))
ember.debug.js:7062WARNING: Encountered "page_count" in payload, but no model was found for model name "page-count" (resolved model name using ember-drupal@serializer:application:.modelNameFromPayloadKey("page_count"))
ember.debug.js:7062WARNING: Encountered "page_size" in payload, but no model was found for model name "page-size" (resolved model name using ember-drupal@serializer:application:.modelNameFromPayloadKey("page_size"))
ember.debug.js:7062WARNING: Encountered "total_items" in payload, but no model was found for model name "total-item" (resolved model name using ember-drupal@serializer:application:.modelNameFromPayloadKey("total_items"))
ember.debug.js:7062WARNING: Encountered "page" in payload, but no model was found for model name "page" (resolved model name using ember-drupal@serializer:application:.modelNameFromPayloadKey("page"))
```

Let me know if there's any other info/code that I need to include.

### EDIT

## Note: The API developer did change it from 'nid' to 'id'

Sometimes you just need to start with a clean slate, huh?

This is now what my serializer looks like and it works as expected:

```
export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
    normalizeResponse(store, primaryModelClass, payload, id, requestType) {
        payload = { article: payload._embedded[primaryModelClass.modelName] };
        return this._super(store, primaryModelClass, payload, id, requestType);
    },
});
```